# android studio - How can I delete an entire child by using its child value in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android and i want to delete a child in database using its child value irrespective of its parent name.
[Here is an image of my realtime-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re4n4.png)

I want to delete 2 child(i.e "Appointment1 06:00 PM" and "Appointment1") as shown in image using a common child value "bookingid : 1001".

Comment: What have you tried in code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit --

Hey! Since you want to iterate for every child, I strongly suggest you change your database structure.

1. Change your table name "Appointment1 time" / "Appointment1" to "1001"(Bookingid value). You can create a field named title and store "Appointment1 time".
2. Then make the table "1001" a direct child of Appointments. You can also add the shop name as a field inside the table "1001".
3. Use unique id as shop id and save it inside the appointments instead of the shop name.
4. Save a copy of Appointments inside shop table as well.

> **Have a look at the images I have attached for better understanding.**

[Appointments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3rBE.png), [Shop table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UttVp.png), [User table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/two8i.png).

Once you structure your database the operations become simple.

- Since you know bookingid, Use the code below to fetch table 1001(or any bookingid) from Appointment table.
- Fetch ShopId and customerID stored in table 1001.
- Goto Shop table and use the shopid You just fetched and inside its appointments table delete 1001.
- Similarly, Goto Users table and use the customerid you just fetched and inside appointments delete 1001.

  ```
   bookingid = "1001" ;
   //set reference to 1001 inside appointments table
   DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointment").child(bookingid);
   //fetch shopid and customerid
   String shopid = databaseReference.child("shopid").getValue();
   String customerid = databaseReference.child("customerid").getValue();  
   //Once you have shopid and customerid, delete 1001 in appointments
   databaseReference.removeValue();
   //Remove tables inside Shop and Users
   databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shop").child(shopid).child("Appointment").child(bookingid);
   databaseReference..removeValue();
   databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(customerid).child("Appointment").child(bookingid).removeValue();  
   databaseReference..removeValue();
  ```

---

Old Answer--

If you know the actual path, use

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("pathToAppointment");
if(databaseReference.child("bookingid").getValue() == "1001"){
    databaseReference.removeValue();
}
```

You can do the same with both appointment tables. Just provide a proper path for databaseReference.

If you don't know the path or if you want to iterate all appointments to fetch the one which has bookingid 1001 then the implementation is bit different. And in that case, I also recommend you to structure database for more effectiveness. Post a comment if you want to do it that way.

Comment: Yes , I don't know the path but I want  to iterate all the appointments and fetch the one having bookingid : 1001 and delete them. Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: Check the answer, I have added some pics of a proper database structure. I strongly suggest you modify your database structure. Try using the push function for generating random-unique id's. Do not nest your database too much. Always make sure you have your table name(key)handy, like adding it as a field inside a linked table. So you can fetch it whenever necessary. Follow a convention in naming. I see you have a table named user and you have field customerid inside the appointments table. That can lead to confusion in extending functions. Let me know if you have any queries.